# How can I do systemverilog code snippets in-place substitution

Tags: macros, include, verilog, system-verilog, register-transfer-level

Let's say I have a 5000 lines of RTL .sv file called **main.sv**, and inside there is a always_comb block, like so:

```
always_comb begin
 //2000 lines of code here
end
```

I'm trying to cut and paste this big always_comb into another separate file called **sub.sv** and replace it with

```
`include "sub.sv"
```

**in the same place** inside main.sv file where the big always_comb once was, for better readability and concise.

The problem I'm having right now is vcs compile throws syntax error on the sub.sv file I created, it simply say it does not expect "always_comb begin" on the 1st line. I guess (although not sure) this is because vcs thinks this file as an .sv file and expects a sv module definition at the beginning.

I looked for other ways using macro online but cannot find a example for my case. What do you think is the correct or better way of doing this kind of in-place code substitution in Systemverilog?

Comment: Do **not** list the sub.sv on the command line. Let the compiler find it, as @toolic suggested. Also IMHO, you are shooting yourself in the foot using this methodology. The maintenance and debugging could be miserable in this case. Readability is questionable.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your sub.sv file to **sub.svh**
i.e. *system verilog header* 
Also you ***don't need to compile*** this file since it contains no modules.
Also make sure to pass the path of this file to the tool if its in different folder